# Can Nginx be used instead of Gunicorn to manage multiple local OpenERP worker servers?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, odoo, gunicorn

I'm currently using **Nginx** as a web server for **Openerp**. It's used to handle SSL and cache static data.
I'm considering extending it's use to also handle fail over and load balancing with a second server, using the `upstream` module.

In the process, it occurred to me that Nginx could also do this on multiple Openerp servers on the same machine, so I can take advantage of multiple cores. But **Gunicorn** seems to the the preferred tool for this.

The question is: can Nginx do a good job handling traffic to multiple local OpenERP servers, bypassing completely the need for Gunicorn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let first talk what they both are bascially.

**Nginx** is a pure web server that's intended for serving up static content and/or redirecting the request to another socket to handle the request.

**Gunicorn** is based on the pre-fork worker model. This means that there is a central master process that manages a set of worker processes. The master never knows anything about individual clients. All requests and responses are handled completely by worker processes.

If you see closely Gunicorn is Designed from Unicron, Follow the [link](https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn) for the detail more diff 
which show the ngix and unicrom same model work on Gunicron also.

Comment: Is there a good reason why I would add Gunicorn to my stack if I'm already using Nginx?

Comment: but they both are Specialist of Different layer, You can not ask Cardiologist to the Brain Operation and Same way you can not ask Neurosurgeon to  the Open Heart Operation, although both are in Same Profession, Doctor ;)

Answer (score -3):

nginx is not a "pure web server" :) It's rather a web accelerator capable of doing load balancing, caching, SSL termination, request routing AND static content. A "pure web server" would be something like Apache - historically a web server for static content, CGIs and later for mod_something.